# How to extract table row value using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want the jquery code (in Firebug) to access the value: ADEPG0568N in the following table, please help.
I could write up to : $('.form_table tr:eq(1)'); to get the row. But then how to access the second td within it?

```
<table class="form_table" width="90%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr class="orange_header">
<tr class="BodyTdOdd">
<tr class="BodyTdOdd">
<td width="50%" align="Right">PAN&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td width="50%">
<b>ADEPG0568N</b>
</td>
</tr>
....
```

Comment: What's up with all those non-closed table row tags? You can't nest tablerows, and all sensible browsers will just push them out into the root of the tbody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
var item= $("table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)");
alert(item.text());
});
</script>
```

2 gets the second element, 1 would be 'PAN'

Comment: but I want 2nd tr within  tbody

Answer (score 0):

extract all tds in table as follow: you can customise as per your requirements

```
$('#form_table tr').each(function() {
var $tds = $(this).find('td');
if($tds.length != 0) {
var $currText = $tds.eq(0).text();
alert('Curr Source Language: ' + $currText);
}
});
```

to select particular cell you can write

```
$('#form_table tr').each(function() {
    var td2 = $(this).find("td").eq(2).text();    
});
```

refer http://forum.jquery.com/topic/get-text-of-td-element-in-a-table